# Change BG color of SVProgessHud in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress

I have worked many times with SVProgressHUD and its cool,
Now the query is,
Is there any ways to change the color of SVProgressHUD depending upon the status?
Say,

1. If its **SUCCESS** then the BG color (Dark grayish) must be **GREEN**
2. If its **ERROR** then the BG color must be **RED**
3. Some other color for just loading.

I am trying this since last days but everything Failed.

I know It can be done by creating my own custom View and implement it accordingly, But won't it be great if somebody has already created it and I can use it.

If the above changes can be done in SVProgressHUD then its well and good, But if not then Can anyone please Provide me an alternate ProgressHUD for the same

**EDIT:**  I have already tried using `UIAppearance`.
The problem there is Say that we have set green color for Success and Red color for error,

Now when the success occurs for the first time then it is of default color and after that whole loading will be of green color So even if after success error occurs for the first time it will be of green color,

and then after executing this the indicator will be of  redcolor,

So the main thing is it does not reflect immediately but reflects second time after the code .is executed

Answer (score 5):

You can Customize the BG Color of SVProgressHUD in this way

```
-(void)showWithStatusSuccess
  {
  [[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4]];
  [[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudForegroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
  [[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Wide" size:16]];
  [[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudStatusShadowColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
  [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Great Success!"];
 }


-(void)showWithStatusError {
   [[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4]];
//[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudForegroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
   [[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Wide" size:16]];
 //[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudStatusShadowColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
   [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Failed with Error"];
  }
```

**Edit:**
In your case you need to change BGColor of SVProgressHUD in showSuccessWithStatus and showErrorWithStatus Methods.so Go to SVProgressHUD.m file change you code like

```
#pragma mark - Show then dismiss methods

+ (void)showSuccessWithStatus:(NSString *)string {
[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4]];
//[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudForegroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Wide" size:16]];
[self showImage:[[self sharedView] hudSuccessImage] status:string];
}

+ (void)showErrorWithStatus:(NSString *)string {
[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4]];
//[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudForegroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Wide" size:16]];
//[[SVProgressHUD appearance] setHudStatusShadowColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
//[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Error"];

[self showImage:[[self sharedView] hudErrorImage] status:string];
}
```

Hope it work for you.

Comment: setHudBackgroundColor does not seem to be a method on SVProgressHUD anymore :(

Answer (score 3):

You can change the color only after you change the defaultStyle to custom. For example, this will change the ring to green.

```
[SVProgressHUD setDefaultStyle:SVProgressHUDStyleCustom];
[SVProgressHUD setForegroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[SVProgressHUD show];
```

Other customization methods are [here on github](https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD).

Comment: How can I set the image in place of spinner in SVProgressHUD?

Comment: @Ramakrishna I've actually haven't touched the spinner for a few months now, but if you look in the .h file of the SVProgressHUD class, there are properties and methods for dealing with images. Not sure if they can replace the spinner. You might have to dig into the .m file for that.

Answer (score 1):

MBProgressHUD https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD is also great.

**UPDATE:**
Try this:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.color = [UIColor redColor];
```

You can create category for MBProgressHUD and so you don't have to keep redefining the above everytime you want to use it. Example:

```
+ (MBProgressHUD *)showFlashHUDMessageTo:(UIView *) view message:(NSString *) message duration:(NSInteger) duration animated:(BOOL) animated
{
    MBProgressHUD *flashMessage = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:view animated:animated];
    [flashMessage setAnimationType:MBProgressHUDAnimationFade];
    [flashMessage setMode:MBProgressHUDModeText];
    flashMessage.labelText = message;
    [flashMessage setMinShowTime:duration];
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:view animated:animated];
    return flashMessage;
}
```

For displaying a flash message for a X duration. You can do the same for customising the background colors for each scenario, etc. Hope you get the drift.

Comment: the background color property changes the background color of hte whole view except hte HUD :)

Comment: I was referring to MBProgressHUD's color property (don't do setBackgroundColor!). I just tried it and works fine. Show me how you did it. You can also customise the other colors within the HUD. You will need to read the doco in MBProgressHUD.h

Comment: Okay @maethor, Working great, But the only thing is I have to allocate it each time I need to use it, Like allocate for Loading then allocate for showing success/error, Hide unhide with sleep :(

Comment: Updated my answer to show how you can customise it and reuse it.

Comment: Need to do Little more workout than SVProgressHUD but working fine. Thanks

Comment: This is definitely the best answer, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in `SVProgressHUD` itself

What you need is a flag which shows whether you are showing the for error or success. What you want to do is to find out 
`- (UIColor *)hudBackgroundColor` method in **SVProgressHUD.m** file

And there you can set the color

Say for example :

```
if (obj.isError == 1) { //For Error Status
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
}
else if (obj.isError == 0) { //For Success Status
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:255 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
}
else {//The Default one OR whatever you like to Set for Loading indicator BG
     return [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.8];
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just had one problem that soon after loading If i need to show success/error it was displaying the default color(may be because of singleton). So for loading I took different class and for showing red/green I used SVProgressHud. But nevermind finally it worked :)